# AntiForgeryToken causing redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, antiforgerytoken

So I have a very simple form on my page which looks like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    // some other fields go here

    <input type="submit" value="DoStuff" />
}
```

and the action looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // Do some stuff here and return
}
```

first of all, if I do not give the `AntiForgeryToken` method a salt parameter it does not generate any hidden field or anything like that containing a token, so clicking that submit button redirects to the error page, which says `required anti forgery field is not present`. Now, if I put any salt in there, for instance Username

```
Html.AntiForgeryToken(User.Identity.Name); // I Use FormsAuthentication
```

then the browser says, web page has a redirect loop. this is the first time I'm using AntiForgeryToken so I don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone help me out. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you really checked if Html.AntiForgeryToken() does not generate any hidden field? In fact it should generate a hidden field by default even if you do not pass any salt.

Comment: yeah I've checked. The generated form contains every field I need except for the toke one.

Comment: Are cookies enabled? do you see anti-forgery cookie set when you load the form? what happens if you give a random guid as a param for `Html.AntyForgeryToken(Guid.NewGuid())`?

Comment: If it means anything, I just see one overload of AntuForgeryToken method in razor view. other are missing in IntelliSense. But if I go to definition of HtmlHelper there are 3 of those methods.

Comment: cookis are enabled. If I give anything as a salt parameter the the field is generated cookie is also present but the post action causes redirec loop

Comment: not only that action. but every. I mean this form is the part of whole layout so every page causes browser redirect loop

Comment: the problem here was the missing @ before before Html.AnfiForgeryToken()

Comment: but why did the redirect loop occur anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Html extensions:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Always generates a hidden field, even if no salt has been passed as a parameter. 
What is more the anti-CSRF capabilities of MVC actually depend on two tokens: one is a hidden form element, and the other is a cookie. So the Html.AntiForgeryToken() helper doesn't just return an HTML snippet. It also has a side effect of setting this cookie. So you need to make sure that cookies are enabled.

Btw any other overload of this method apart from the parameterless one is obsolete:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: What a shame. I I called that method without @ symbol. :/ I've put @ before Html.AntiForgeryToken() and everything works fine. But can you explain why the redirect loop happened ?

Comment: Can you check if this causes a redirect loop also in case you would pass as a salt Guid.NewGuid() or just some string value instead of User.Identity.Name?

Comment: I think yes. The action which form is posted to to some page. and redirect loop happened to that page. I mean when I pressed that submit button many request were made to that page. and than the browser stopped it all.